# To show 'dual' of a Projective is projective

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, projective-module, representation-of-algebras

I am reading Chapter IV, section 2 in Assem's book *Elements of the Representation Theory of Associative Algebras* and I am stuck at a claim:

Let $A$ be a finite dimensional algebra over $\mathbb{C}$.
Then $Hom_{A}(eA, A) \cong Ae$ where $e$ is a primitive idempotent.... (*)
This is needed to prove that $Hom_{A}(P, A)$ is a projective left $A$ module if $P$ is a finite dimensional projective right $A$ module.

What I get is $Hom_{A}(eA, A) \cong A$, since I only need to assign an image to $e$ to determine a homormorphism from $eA$ to $A$. So where am I wrong? HOw to get $Ae$?

Comment: You are considering right $A$-modules, so the image assigned to $e$ by $\varphi$ will be $\varphi(e)=\varphi(ee)=\varphi(e)e\in Ae$.

Comment: You say you only need to assign an image to $e$, but you cannot assign *any* image. You are not dealing with a free module here.

Comment: @CaptainLama ah! yes....$Ae$ is a free $Ae$ module not a free $A$ module